# p4java client setRoot not working

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec, p4java

Using p4java to sync files on various machines, so I'm using IClient.setRoot() to change the root accordingly. But IClient.setRoot() doesn't actually change the root in the client object.I looked in the debugger right after the setRoot() call

Here's my code after connecting to the server.

client is an IClient and p4Server is an IServer.

the prop functions are simply pulling properties entries for workspace and root dir

What am I missing to make setRoot() work. Thanks!

```
client = p4Server.getClient(prop.getString("perforce.workspace"));
if (client == null) {
    logger.error("Failed to fetch workspace: {}", prop.getString("perforce.workspace"));
} else {
    File p4Dir = new File(prop.getPath("perforce.scripts.dest"));
    if (!p4Dir.exists()) {
        p4Dir.mkdirs();
    }

    client.setRoot(p4Dir.getPath());
    logger.debug("Setting p4sync dest root to: {}",p4Dir.getPath() );
    p4Server.setCurrentClient(client);
```

Answer (score 1):

You must update the client on the server - the setCurrentClient() does not do this.

```
client.setRoot(p4Dir.getPath());
logger.debug("Setting p4sync dest root to: {}",p4Dir.getPath() );
client.update();
p4Server.setCurrentClient(client);
```